# UIAlertView does not show up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

Take a look at the following code, the problem is that the AlertView does not show up, even if I see in debug that the code is been executed.

Please advice.

Many thanks

Eran

```
    -(void)displayABC:(id)sender
{

    static int index = 0;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ABC" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *ABCArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if(index < [ABCArray count])
        [authButton setTitle:[ABCArray objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    index++;


    if (index > [ABCArray count]){

        UIAlertView *endOfABCAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"XXX" message:@"XXX" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:endOfABCAlertView];

    }
}
```

I am using the latest Xcode 4.6.3 (is it a bug with the simulator? maybe ?)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't calling:

```
[endOfABCAlertView show];
```

If you can spare 3 minutes to look into header [Displaying in Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html), you will find it.

Comment: Thanks, ye I was thinking I needed it as subview, that is what I was remembered. anyway thanks for fixing my mistake... I still need to figure it out how to recognise that the user clicked cancel or done button in order to process to the right method, any idea ? I mean if the user click canceled on the AlertView I want to do method X if the user clicked on OK I want to do method Y. ideas ?

Comment: read the documentation... you will find everything. And yes you will feel, that you will loose 15 minutes, but in 15 minutes you will know many things that will help you in future.

Answer (score 1):

`[endOfABCAlertView show]` is the way to show it. Do not add it as a subview.

**Edit:**
The way to check what button was cancelled is by using the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol. See the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) for the specifics.

Comment: Thanks isaach, ye I was thinking I needed it as subview, that is what I was remembered. anyway thanks for fixing my mistake... I still need to figure it out how to recognise that the user clicked cancel or done button in order to process to the right method, any idea ? I mean if the user click canceled on the AlertView I want to do method X if the user clicked on OK I want to do method Y. ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[self.view addSubview:endOfABCAlertView]`; and add `[endOfABCAlertView show];` That will do..

Comment: Thanks Geeniewanted, I did that and it worked, not sure I was thinking to add it as subview I am bit rusty, it will come back to me in a week or two.. I need to sharp my brain... thanks man. Eran

Comment: How do you know if the user clicked cancel or for example done button, is there a way to know in the code ?

Comment: Sure.. Cheers! Keep coding.

Comment: Thanks, ye I was thinking I needed it as subview, that is what I was remembered. anyway thanks for fixing my mistake... I still need to figure it out how to recognise that the user clicked cancel or done button in order to process to the right method, any idea ? I mean if the user click canceled on the AlertView I want to do method X if the user clicked on OK I want to do method Y. ideas ?

Comment: Yes, if you have two buttons (Say example, you have "Done" and "Cancel" button in your UIAlertView), you can find it using buttonIndex.

Comment: Take a look at this example. http://getsetgames.com/2009/12/02/iphonedev-advent-tip-2-how-to-show-an-alert-with-uialertview/

Comment: In this example, - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {} does the trick!!

Comment: Fantastic !!!! thanks man :-) are you on twitter ? I would like to connect with you. thanks again for all the help.

Comment: There is small bug in your example, as the OK button is at index 1 and in your example print the NSLog at index 0

Comment: An Index starts with 0. You have "OK" and "Cancel" button. OK = 0, Cancel = 1. Hence, you press OK, you get to see NSLog printing "User pressed OK". :)